# How to use ANY VALUES in repository query

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to create query like:

```
SELECT *FROM user WHERE name = ANY (VALUES ('Name1'), ('Name2') ...)
```

Can anyone help me to understand how I can implement it as native @Query in JPA repository?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u where u.name = ANY **.....**", native = true) 
User findUsersByName(List<String> names);
```

Now I can't find solution to set names as **VALUES ('Name1'), ('Name2')...**

Comment: Since you are comparing the values with equals operator `=` I would rather change my SQL to `.. where u.name in :values` then it would be easy to assign a parameter.

Comment: @mndeveci, the variant with VALUES that is described in the question is much more productive.

Comment: I understand but can you make it more elaborate, about what is the difference between `IN` and `VALUES` in this case?

Comment: @mndeveci, I am trying to improve IN requests and I found solution with VALUES here https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/ You can read of request speed improvements in this article in details. After testing request from psql console  I saw that values requests mach more faster. Now I am trying to use it in repository, but cant find solution :(

Comment: Ohh I understand now. Maybe you can check this discussion; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601318/how-to-use-the-postgres-any-clause-with-jpa-hibernate-native-queries-array-para