# How to using like array of string HIBERNATE

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying to pass an array of string as a parameter to my query but I get the following error

> ERROR: operator does not exist: text ~~ record Dica: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Here is my query

```
select * from table where value  like any (array[?1]);
```

when I run it using hibernate the query is like:

```
 select * from table where value  like any (array[('%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%')]);
```

There's a best way to pass my array as parameter?? I think that is important to say that my array is dynamic so i can't fiz it in my query.

Answer (score 0):

- **First** use `createNativeQuery` instead of `createQuery` as syntax is native to PSQL.
- **Second** query syntax should be `select * from table where value like any (array?1)` as `?1` will be substituted by `['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%']`, so your end query will match required PSQL syntax.
  `select * from table where value like any (array['%foo%', '%bar%', '%baz%'])`

Comment: Well, i've tried your suggestion but i can't use "... like any (array?1)" because i get the error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "?"

Comment: There are certain posts which might help you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgresql-array-with-hibernate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601318/how-to-use-the-postgres-any-clause-with-jpa-hibernate-native-queries-array-para
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your syntax is wrong.

Instead of:

```
select * from table where value  like any (array[?1]);
```

You should use:

```
select * from table where value like any (:vals);
```

You cannot use `array[?]` or `array[:var]` to construct the variable. That is invalid syntax.

Secondly for Hibernate 5.2 up to 5.4 you can just add [this dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-array-contributor/1.0) and you can use the most common object arrays directly. Primitive arrays are not supported and are not supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

use setParameterList method.

```
String queryStr = "select * from table where value in :valueList";

Query query = SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryStr);


query.setParameterList("valueList", new Object[]{"%foo%","%bar%","%baz%"});
```

Please note that I used in clause and it doesn't support wildcard characters such as %.